# Display iframe's content (not placeholder) in TinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce

is there a way of displaying the actual content/render of embeded iframe inside the TinyMCE editor not just a placeholder as its set by defualt? See attached screen grab below:

[image: iframe placeholder]

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The placeholder is caused by the [media plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3amedia). Check your [plugins](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aplugins) configuration. Disabling it will however also cause placeholders on flash objects and the likes to disappear.